# Laravel cacheable images in the browser

Tags: laravel, routes, browser-cache, laravel-mix

As a developer, I want to be in control of browser's cache. I don't want to just disable it.
I like the way laravel `mix()` works. But how can I use it for images? 
More specifically, for images that are being hardcoded in CSS files.
Like

```
background-image: url('/my_image.png');
```

I know it is not quite a task for the 'mix()' function.

Thus, I created some sort of a global variable (like a counter). If I change it (increment it once), all the cached images would be refreshed in the all of my clients' browsers.

My idea was to make a route like this

```
Route::get('cacheable/1/images/{filename?}', [SomeController::class, 'get_image'])
  ->where('filename', '.*')
  ->name('cacheable.images');
```

and then I can call it like that

```
route('cacheable.images', 'smile.png');
```

I can change `1` to '2' and be sure, all the customer requests are now being pointed to a new route, and the images are found in a new route.

But now I needed to hardcode images in the css files. And now I must not only change the url in the route file, but also go through all css in search of images. It breaks the idea of a single point of truth.
And it breaks my heart.

Any suggestion of how can I sync the `mix()` function and the 'Route::get' function?